# Expect: SSH into a remote host, run a command, and save its output to a variable

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to ssh into a server, run a command, and save its output to a variable, with no success.

```
spawn $env(SHELL)
expect "\$ "
send "ls\r"
expect "\$ "
send "ssh myserver1\r"
expect "\$ "
send "cd /tmp/remotedir1\r"
expect "\$ "
send "ls\r"
expect "\$ "
set myvar1 [exec ls]
puts "The value of \$myvar1 is: "
puts $myvar1
send "exit\r"
expect "\$ "
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

When I run it, I get:

```
spawn /bin/bash
$ ls
localfile1      localfile2       localfile3
$ ssh myserver1
Last login: Tue Sep 10 15:45:07 2017 from 192.168.0.100
myserver1$ cd /tmp/remotedir1
myserver1$ ls
remotefile1
myserver1$ The value of $myvar1 is:
localfile1
localfile2
localfile3
exit
logout
Connection to myserver1 closed.
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
```

Apparently, instead of setting $myvar1 to "remotefile1", it sets to those 3 files in the $cwd on the local host.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `exec` will execute the command locally.

Upon sending the `ls` command, you have to make use of the `expect_out` array to get the response.

```
set prompt "(.*)(#|%|>|\\\$) $"
send "ls\r"
expect -re $prompt
puts $expect_out(1,string)
```

Comment: Thanks. Although your sample code doesn't give me exactly what I wanted, I got the idea of using the $expect_out keyword to take the output of the previous send command.